# return empty set when two lists match python

Tags: python

```
my_list = [['mango', 'apple', 'mango'], ['papaya', 'orange'], ['berry', ' berry'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

So if a sublist contains two identical variables, it is reduced to an empty list. So output should be

```
my_list = [[], ['papaya', 'orange'], [], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

Desired output

```
my_list = [['papaya', 'orange'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

So berry being the identical variable is reduced to an empty set. And the same goes for mango.

```
i = 0
j = 0
for x in my_list[i]:
   for y in my_list[j]:
      if x == not x:
         list[i][j].pop()
      else:
         continue
print my_list
```

Can it be done using list comprehension?

Adding to my question:

```
my_list = [['not mango', 'apple', 'mango'], ['not papaya', 'orange'], ['berry', 'not berry'],['watermelon', 'banana']
```

Output:

```
my_list = [['not papaya, orange'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with ternary operator, comparing the size of the sublist with the size of a set created from that sublist.

```
>>> my_list = [['mango','apple','mango'],['papaya','orange'],['berry','berry'],['watermelon','banana']]
>>> [lst if len(lst) == len(set(lst)) else [] for lst in my_list]
[[], ['papaya', 'orange'], [], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

Or use a conditional list comprehension in case you want to completely remove those lists (not really clear from your question what you want).

```
>>> [lst for lst in my_list if len(lst) == len(set(lst))]
[['papaya', 'orange'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

---

About your edited question: If you want to check whether for any `"x"`, `"not x"` is also in the list, you can not just compare sizes but have to use `any`:

```
>>> my_list = [['mango', 'apple', 'not mango'], ['not papaya', 'orange'], ['berry', 'not berry'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
>>> [lst if not any("not " + x in lst for x in lst) else [] for lst in my_list]
[[], ['not papaya', 'orange'], [], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

If you want to removed the lists entirely, just put the condition at the back, as above.

Comment: So upvote for the correct, earliest, and with full explanation answer :)

Comment: @Belle See my edit. Also, when editing a question, please _add_ to the question instead of totally altering the question, thus making all existing answers invalid.

Comment: Oh..sorry...I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [ ["mango","apple","mango"],["papaya","orange"],["berry","berry"],["watermelon","banana"] ]
print [i for i in my_list if len(i)==len(set(i))]
```

Output:

```
[['papaya', 'orange'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

And with empty lists:

```
my_list = [ ["mango","apple","mango"],["papaya","orange"],["berry","berry"],["watermelon","banana"] ]
print [i if len(i)==len(set(i)) else [] for i in my_list]
```

Ouput:

```
[[], ['papaya', 'orange'], [], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['mango','apple','mango'],['papaya','orange'],['berry','berry'],['watermelon','banana']]
print [i for i in my_list if not any(i.count(j)>1 for j in i)]
```

Output:`[['papaya', 'orange'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]`

You can use `any` here to see if any element gets repeated.

If you want empty list use

```
my_list = [['mango','apple','mango'],['papaya','orange'],['berry','berry'],['watermelon','banana']]
print [i if not any(i.count(j)>1 for j in i) else [] for i in my_list ]
```

Output:`[[], ['papaya', 'orange'], [], ['watermelon', 'banana']]`

Comment: This will have quadratic complexity. Also, this removes sublists instead of replacing them with empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set`. `set` contains unique element. So, the idea is to check the length
of `set` with length of the `list`. If both are not same. then there exist duplicate element otherwise not.

```
print [ innerList if len(innerList)==len(set(innerList)) else [] for innerList in my_list ]
```

Comment: I never thought of using len(). Tweaking my question a bit. What if

Comment: I never thought of using len(). Tweaking my question a bit. What if `my_list = [['apple', 'orange', 'not apple'], ['not papaya', 'orange'], ['berry', 'not berry'], ['watermelon', 'banana']` is my input?  Varied views are welcome. Meaning not just list comprehension. Its interesting to look at problem in different ways. And yes, I do not want empty lists. So my output should still be `my_list = [['not papaya', 'orange'], ['watermelon', 'banana']]`

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [['mango','apple','mango'],['papaya','orange'],['berry','berry'],['watermelon','banana']]


from collections import Counter

my_list = [ []  if max(Counter(x).values()) > 1 else x for x in my_list]

pp(my_list)

[[], ['papaya', 'orange'], [], ['watermelon', 'banana']]
```